# how to change the value of an array through a onclick canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Guys this sounds like a simple problem, but I'm having trouble solving it. Basically, the function desenhaFaceTot() allows drawing three dices on three different canvas through a button and assigning the numArray value to each dice drawing the dice points according to the number that came out (example: n = 5 draws five points) and then arranges the dices in ascending order this does everything well the problem is that: I wanted to change the value of the first dice (the smallest number in the array) by pressing the canvas in the alterarNumero() function and arrange it later instead my program changes the value of any of the dice.

Example of an operation I wanted to happen

Dices:

1 3 4

after pressing the first canvas onclick: (the number that came out is, for example, six)

3 4 6

What happens in my code instead of changing the value of the first dice changed any of the dice in the case changed for example the dice number 3 and put the number 6

1 3 6

(half the code is drawing stuff on the canvas)

```js
function inic(){
    adqInterf();
    desenhoDado(graf1);
    desenhoDado(graf2);
    desenhoDado(graf3);            
}

function adqInterf(){
    graf1 = document.getElementById("tela1").getContext("2d");
    graf2 = document.getElementById("tela2").getContext("2d");
    graf3 = document.getElementById("tela3").getContext("2d");
}
function desenhaFaceTotal(){
    desenhoDado(graf1);
    desenhoDado(graf2);
    desenhoDado(graf3);             
    
    var numArray = [n, n2, n3];
    
    numArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
                         
    desenhaFace(numArray[0], graf1);
    desenhaFace(numArray[1], graf2);
    desenhaFace(numArray[2], graf3);
}
--------------------------------
function desenhaFaceTot(){
    n = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;
    n2 = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;
    n3 = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;

    numArray = [n, n2, n3];
    desenhaFaceTotal(); 
}


function alterarNumero(){                   
    n = Math.floor(6 * Math.random()) + 1;                  
    desenhaFaceTotal();
}
function desenhaFace(dado, cgrafico){
    if(dado==1){
        desenho1(cgrafico);
    }                   
    if(dado==2){
        desenho2(cgrafico);
    }
    if(dado==3){
        desenho1(cgrafico);
        desenho2(cgrafico);
    }   
    if(dado==4){
        desenho4(cgrafico);
    }
    if(dado==5){
        desenho4(cgrafico);
        desenho1(cgrafico);
    }
    if(dado==6){
        desenho6(cgrafico);
    }                       
}
function pintaRect(cGraf, x1, y1, r, corP, opac, espL){
    cGraf.fillStyle = corP;
    cGraf.globalAlpha = opac;
    cGraf.lineWidth = espL;
    
    cGraf.beginPath();
    cGraf.moveTo(x1-20, y1);
    cGraf.arcTo(x1, y1, x1, x1, r);
    cGraf.arcTo(x1, x1, y1, x1, r);
    cGraf.arcTo(y1, x1, y1, y1, r);
    cGraf.arcTo(y1, y1, x1, y1, r);
    cGraf.closePath();
    cGraf.fill();
}

function pintaCirc(cGraf, x, y, raio, corP, espL){
    cGraf.fillStyle = corP;
    cGraf.lineWidth = espL;
    
    cGraf.beginPath();
    cGraf.arc(x, y, raio, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    cGraf.closePath();
    cGraf.fill();
}

function desenhoDado(cgraf){
    pintaRect(cgraf, 84, 9, 15, "#223322", 1, 1);
}
function desenho1(cgraf){
    pintaCirc(cgraf, 44, 44, 7, "#804000", 5);
}

function desenho2(cgraf){
    pintaCirc(cgraf, 25, 25, 7, "#804000", 5);
    pintaCirc(cgraf, 63, 63, 7, "#804000", 5);
}

function desenho4(cgraf){
    desenho2(cgraf);
    pintaCirc(cgraf, 25, 63, 7, "#804000", 5);
    pintaCirc(cgraf, 63, 25, 7, "#804000", 5);
}

function desenho6(cgraf){
    desenho4(cgraf);
    pintaCirc(cgraf, 25, 44, 7, "#804000", 5);
    pintaCirc(cgraf, 63, 44, 7, "#804000", 5);
}
```

```html
<body onload="inic()">
      <canvas class="dados" id="tela1" width="88" height="88" onclick="alterarNumero()"></canvas>
            <canvas class="dados" id="tela2" width="88" height="88"></canvas>
            <canvas class="dados" id="tela3" width="88" height="88"></canvas>
      <button class="botao" id="botaoNovaMao" onclick="desenhaFaceTot()">nova<br>mão</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Answer based on comment. When you are changing `n` you are changing it on the original array before the sort. The sort does not change the order of the original array that is above it. So as you can see here in this console log I have logged `numArray` before the sort and after. I also logged `n` so you can see what's happening.

```
//intial load
"before 1,5,6"
"after 1,5,6"
//clicked dice once and drew a 6
"n 6"
"before 6,5,6" //<---replaced 1 with 6
"after 5,6,6" //now sorted the array
//clicked again and drew a 3
"n 3"
"before 3,5,6"  //but look here the second and third are 5 & 6 NOT 6 & 6 because `numArray` was not mutated by sort. so it is now going to process the array as it was above in the before state not the after one that you see on screen
"after 3,5,6"
```